# IE7 JS pop up mask displaying above the popup box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having great problems solving this IE 7 bug, It works fine in every other browser but IE7

below is a dev link
http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/

If you go to the top right and press info and contact in IE7 the mask appears above the popup box, I was wondering if anyone else has got the same problem as this. Below is my CSS and Jquery.

CSS Mask:

```
#mask {
display: none;
background: #000;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0.8;
z-index: 999;}
```

Jquery:

```
$('a.info , a.info_footer').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    $("#popup").load("/info.html");
    // Getting the variable's value from a link
    var 
    show = $('#popup').css('display', 'block'),
    popup = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $(popup).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border
    var popMargTop = ($(popup).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(popup).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(popup).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: IE7 is fewer than 1% of all users... Is it even worth the time to fix it?

Comment: I believe it is, if my employer sees it not working properly it reflect badly on me

Comment: I don't know how to fix the `z-index` problem, but an improvement is fixing the transparency on IE7. IE7 and IE8 [do not support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity) the CSS `opacity` property. As a replacement, you can use `filter: alpha(opacity=80);` (code [from QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html)). Now you can at least see the pop-up, though it's still under the `#mask`, even if I set the `z-index` of `#mask` to 0.